# PHP/Java Bridge. How to connect from php server to desktop App

Tags: java, php

I'm testing PHP/Java Bridge connection. And I have a simple example yet.
The php file is:

```
require_once("http://localhost:8087/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
$world = new java("HelloWorld");
echo $world->hello(array("from PHP"));
```

And the java file:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static final String JAVABRIDGE_PORT="8087";
  static final php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner runner = 
    php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner.getInstance(JAVABRIDGE_PORT);

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    runner.waitFor();
    System.exit(0);
  }
  public void hello(String args[]) throws Exception {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hello " + args[0]);
  }
}
```

Everything works fine on one pc. But I have to implement connection from PHP server to java desktop application which is on the another server not on localhost, so "localhost:8087/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc" won't work. In future this java app will print on printer some data from php website.
So I need to call java function remotely. It should be a desktop App because I will write usb connection in future. Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use require_once to include files from another host.

If this option is available, a lot of websites will be at risk.

Why don't you use it from another way, Here are some points that may help:

1. make java calls PHP.
2. write your result to some file in the destination server.
3. Make server reads that file.

If you don't like that, please read about web service, it may have what you need.

Comment: I can't do in this way. I need to run Java function remotely from website. When I click button, java app should run some operations